# Passing several variables to blade view

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I am loading my data like the following:

```
public function details($id)
{

    $instrument = Instruments::join('revisions', 'revisions.id', '=', 'instruments.revisions_id')
        ->where([
            ['revisions.revision_status', '=', '1'],
            ['instruments.id', '=', $id],
        ])
        ->orderBy('instruments.name')
        ->get();

    $team = Team::join('instruments', 'teams.instruments_id', '=', 'instruments.id')
        ->join('revisions', 'revisions.id', '=', 'teams.revisions_id')
        ->where([
            ['revisions.revision_status', '=', '1'],
            ['instruments.id', '=', $id],
        ])
        ->orderBy('instruments.name')
        ->get();


    return view('details')->with('instrumentUnderEdit', $instrument)->with('teamUnderEdit', $team);
}
```

However, in my view I get the following error:

```
ErrorException thrown with message "Property [image] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projects\demo_laravel_screener\resources\views\details.blade.php)"
```

The blade file has the following variable:

```
                <img style="height: 32px; width: 32px;" src="{{ asset('images')}}/{{ $instrumentUnderEdit->image }}" /> {{ $instrumentUnderEdit->name }}
```

Any suggestions why I am getting the error? Do I load the variables wrongly into the view?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: So `get()` gives you a collection, not single object.

Comment: Do you want all rows or single ?

Comment: @user2486 I would like to pass all rows to the frontend. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: You need to loop woth foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `get()` gives you a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-collections) of objects, not a single one, you should modify code:

use `->first()` instead of `->get()`

This will give you a single object with required properties.

Comment: Thx for your answer! How to actually pass a collection of objects to the frontend? Is this the same?

Comment: Yes, the same, and in a template iterate over this collection.